# What means "Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default" and why does this happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

I'm working on a simple presentation website made with Vite and React. In my code I use JavaScript and I encounter this error in my App.jsx file and I don't understand what's wrong. Can someone bring some light here? Thanks.

error: Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default

my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer/Footer";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried to replace the const App with functin App but nothing changed the situation.

Comment: Could you share how you're importing `App` too please?

Comment: Could you share all component code?

Comment: I solved the problem recently, thanks